# contentplaceholder starts from start of the body instead of starting under the navbar

Tags: asp.net, navbar, contentplaceholder

I created a transparent navbar-fixed-top and placed a content place holder after it the transparent navbar is created using rgba(0.0.0.70) when i run a page the data content in the content place holder starts from top of the body and is visible through the navbar.placed it correctly and tried everything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [contentplaceholder content starts from under navbar issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41468264/contentplaceholder-content-starts-from-under-navbar-issue)

Comment: Aside from one component of the RGB value, this is a copy+paste of your question some nine minutes earlier.